# How can I display exceptions normally in iPython?

Tags: python, ipython

I like iPythons way of mixing terminal commands and Python, but I dislike its way of showing exceptions. It looks like this:

```
>>> import foo
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-34d390fb3acc> in <module>()
----> 1 import foo

ImportError: No module named foo
```

I would rather see the normal Python exception printing:

```
>>> import foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named foo
```

I've searched for such a setting in the config but couldn't find it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6):

Set [`xmode`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-xmode) to `plain`:

```
In [8]: %xmode plain
Exception reporting mode: Plain

In [9]: import foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-9-34d390fb3acc>", line 1, in <module>
    import foo
ImportError: No module named 'foo'
```

Or use the corresponding config file entry:

```
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.xmode = 'Plain'
```